# Go non-ascii form values saved as question marks

Tags: mysql, go, utf-8, sqlx

I'm using Go [sqlx package](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) to make queries on MariaDB database and I'd like to be able to save non-ascii form submitted values into the database.

Here is the function:

```
func QuoteCreate(content string, author string) error {
    var err error
    fmt.Println("content, author", content, author)

        _, err = database.SQL.Exec("INSERT INTO quote (content, author) VALUES (?,?)", content, author)

        if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return standardizeError(err)
}
```

The `quote` tables has `utf8_general_cli` colation and `InnoDB` engine. However the `content` and `author` values submitted by form are saved as `???` when the values are not ascii characters (I tried Persian and simplified chinese).

I have also tried `utf8_unicode_cli` for the table colation, but got the same problem. Interestingly, non-ascii characters are shown correctly when printed on terminal befor being saved.

So I'm left clueless what's wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: What encoding is your page, form and server side expecting. Often these default to ISO8859-1, unless you specify explicitly.

Comment: I have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the template.

Comment: what tool are you using to see the content of your db ? are you getting some error in your Go code ?

Comment: @YandryPozo I use phpmyadmin to see the database. I also see the saved characters as rendered in go templates. Both cases show the same `???`. I see no error in terminal.

Comment: As an FYI, the charset meta is only for controlling the rendition of the page. When sending form values there a number of other steps where the character encoding can fall to some default value, before getting to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but these solved the issue:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE quote CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Read about question marks here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored